# javascript version declaration with my site

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a confusion in js i called lot of js version in my site what is the proper way

**I called this way in different page**

```
<link src="js/jquery.min.js"/>
<link src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>  
<link src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"/>
```

I have slider Date picker etc. So if one is working then rest is not working

So How i make it work all

Gallery Slider

```
<?php
foreach($block->getGalleryImages() as $image){ ?>
    <?php if(!$block->isMainImage($image)):?>
        <img src="<?php //echo $image->getData('medium_image_url') ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>

<div class="product-slider">                     

      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ $json=$block->getGalleryImagesJson();
        $array = json_decode($json,true);
        foreach($array as $item)
        {
            $imgurl = $item['full'];?>
        <div class="item">
        <img src="<?php echo $imgurl;?>"/>
        </div>      
        <?php }?>

 </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
      $.noConflict();
      $(".product-slider").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
    margin: 50,
    responsiveClass: true,
    nav: true,
    lazyLoad :true ,
    rewind : false ,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    navText : ["",""],
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        }
        , 768: {
            items: 2
        }
        , 991: {
            items: 1
        }
    }

      });




</script>
```

Date Picker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery("#dt1-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>").datepicker({
                                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                                minDate: 0,
                                onSelect: function (date) {
                                    var dt2 = jQuery('#dt2-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>');
                                    var startDate = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
                                    var minDate = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
                                    //dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                                    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
                                    //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
                                    dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
                                    dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
                                    jQuery(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
                                }
                            });
                            jQuery('#dt2-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>').datepicker({
                                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
                            });
                    </script>


<input type="text" id="dt1-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>">
                    <input type="text" id="dt2-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>">
```

Comment: `<link>` only works for CSS, `<script>` is for JS.

Comment: Maybe you should checkout requirejs

Comment: Don't include two different versions of jQuery

Comment: Magento we can declare either <link> or <script> no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Change the `JavaScript` tags from `<link />` to `<script />`. Link tags are for stylesheets and script tags, well, for scripts;

2 - Load `JavaScript` libraries only once;

3 - Check the URL's and versions you want to load the libraries / stylesheets 
from. I guess you're mixing things up a bit.

See example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to load CSS files, you should write the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you post your html, or whatever you're coding?

Comment: gallery slider it's working like slide the image now it's slide not working

Comment: Can you please post some code, or an URL to your page?

Comment: So, what's not working? Owl carousel? Do you see any error in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: can you please give ma any working script of slider and date picker

Comment: @myTest, i have edited the answer. These links work for me.